# Grails RabbitMQ losing messages when many messages at once

Tags: grails, rabbitmq

I have a Grails application using the grails RabbitMQ plugin to handle messages asynchronously. The queue is set to durable, the messages are persistent, and there are 20 concurrent consumers. Acknowledgement is turned on and is set to issue an ack/nack based on if the consumer returns normally or throws an exception. These consumers usually handle messages fine, but when the queue fills up very quickly (5,000 or so messages at once) some of the messages get lost.

There is logging in the consumer when the message from Rabbit is received and that logging event never occurs, so the consumer is not receiving the lost messages at all. Further, there are no exceptions that appear in the logs.

I have tried increasing the prefetch value of the consumers to 5 (from 1), but that did not solve the problem. I have checked the RabbitMQ UI and there are no messages stuck in the queue and there are no unacknowledged messages.

Comment: Are your publishing applications using publisher confirms? https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#publisher-confirms - I suspect your publishers are dropping messages, not your consumers.

Comment: The publishing application is not using publisher confirms, however we have used firehose on a different environment and confirmed that all messages are being published

Comment: That doesn't really prove anything. Without using publisher confirms, you can't be certain that every message sent to RabbitMQ was routed to a queue. If your publisher can't handle the scenario where RMQ throttles it, or crashes, or experiences a network issue, it's pretty easy to lose a message before it reaches a queue without using confirms. You should review this - https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2018/9/10/how-to-lose-messages-on-a-rabbitmq-cluster. If you can provide a way to reproduce what you see, post it to the `rabbitmq-users` list.

Comment: Thanks Luke, I'll try that out